# Problem with Taylor expansion of a function

Tags: series-expansion

I need to make a Taylor expansion of the following expression:

```
(ρ^2 (-z + z2 + Sqrt[(z - z2)^2 + ρ^2]) (-z + z4 + Sqrt[(z - z4)^2 + ρ^2]))/
   ((-z + z1 + Sqrt[(z - z1)^2 + ρ^2]) (-z + z3 + Sqrt[(z - z3)^2 + ρ^2]))
```

about `ρ = 0` for `z1 <= z <= z2 && z3 <= z <= z4`, where `z1  <= z2 <= z3 <= z4`.

I tried to express the conditions as

```
$Assumptions := z1 <= z <= z2 && z3 <= z <= z4 && z1 <= z2 <= z3 <= z4
```

and I evaluated:

```
Series[
  (ρ^2 (-z + z2 + Sqrt[(z - z2)^2 + ρ^2]) (-z + z4 + Sqrt[(z - z4)^2 + ρ^2])) /
     ((-z + z1 + Sqrt[(z - z1)^2 + ρ^2]) (-z + z3 + Sqrt[(z - z3)^2 + ρ^2])),
  {ρ,0,1}]
```

However, I did not get the correct expansion.

How should I adjust my code to get the correct expressions?

Comment: What code did you use to obtain the expansion?

Comment: I used `Series[(\[Rho]^2 (-z + z2 + Sqrt[(z - z2)^2 + \[Rho]^2]) (-z + z4 + 
   Sqrt[(z - z4)^2 + \[Rho]^2]))/((-z + z1 + 
   Sqrt[(z - z1)^2 + \[Rho]^2]) (-z + z3 + 
   Sqrt[(z - z3)^2 + \[Rho]^2])),{\[Rho],0,1}]` after declaring the assumptions.

Answer (score 3):

```
$Assumptions = 
 Reduce[z1 <= z <= z2 && z3 <= z <= z4 && z1 <= z2 <= z3 <= z4, z]

(* z4 ∈ Reals && z3 <= z4 && z2 == z3 && z1 <= z3 && z == z3 *)

expr = (ρ^2 (-z + z2 + Sqrt[(z - z2)^2 + ρ^2]) (-z + z4 + 
       Sqrt[(z - z4)^2 + ρ^2]))/((-z + z1 + 
       Sqrt[(z - z1)^2 + ρ^2]) (-z + z3 + 
       Sqrt[(z - z3)^2 + ρ^2])) // FullSimplify

(* (ρ^2 (-z3 + z4 + 
   Sqrt[(z3 - z4)^2 + ρ^2]))/(z1 - z3 + Sqrt[(z1 - z3)^2 + ρ^2]) *)

Series[expr, {ρ, 0, 3}] // FullSimplify // Normal

(* 4 (z1 - z3) (z3 - z4) + ((z1 - z3)/(z3 - z4) + (z3 - z4)/(
    z1 - z3)) ρ^2 *)

Limit[expr, ρ -> 0]

(* 4 (z1 - z3) (z3 - z4) *)
```

Comment: Do you put the output in comments in the notebook, or in the StackExchange webpage? What's most efficient?

Comment: @PaulCommentary - I copy and past Input and Output (except graphics) into MSE then comment the Output. Efficiency is probably the same either way.